# Update table: Converting CRLF to LF on linux

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I use oracle database.
I was trying to use replace `CRLF` characters on my `emp` table column.
However, the following does not give me the right result.

```
UPDATE emp t
   SET ename = REPLACE(t.ename, '[CR-LF]', chr(10))
commit;
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The wrong thing is the text you are trying to replace. Use the code of the characters instead:

```
UPDATE emp t
SET ename = REPLACE(t.ename, chr(13) || chr(10), chr(10))
```

Comment: still not working. I was wondering if this table won't allow changes.

Comment: "not working" is not a useful diagnostic. If the DML statement is failing Oracle will be reporting a specific error message which you should be providing.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
UPDATE emp t
   SET ename = TRIM( TRAILING CHR(13) FROM t.ename)
```